# Mixed content blocking behavior in Firefox

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, firefox

In Firefox version 23, mixed content blocking behavior is added.It means that Firefox has blocked content that is insecure on the page you're visiting.It shows the shield icon in the address bar which blocks some uploads in my app.From development side  how to turn off this behavior?? .I am in ruby on rails development.

Can anybody guide me??

Comment: Is your app on https?

Comment: _“From development side how to turn off this behavior?”_ – you mean just in your own browser, for the time you are developing your app? Call `about:config`, and search for `mix` – a few options will turn up.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot turn this off remotely!** Except in your own browser, of course.

That is: Your rails application cannot turn off mixed-content blocking in the browser.

This is a preference only a (skilled) user may change in her browser... But shouldn't in the age of Firesheep, etc.

Instead, **you should make all your active content available via https**.

Or downgrade to insecure http. Since you're essentially wanting to allow Man-In-The-Middle attacks anyway, because that's what mixed-content means, the result of using http in the first place wouldn't be that much different. The only difference would be that a MITM could stay passive in http-only, instead of having to actively modify data in https-mixed-mode. But, seriously, what percentage of your users would recognize an active MITM, who maybe even only runs a small targeted attack?

Comment: I added some emphasis to the most important part.

Comment: My question is cant I disable that behavior from development side so that the icon is disabled in client side also??

Comment: Added yet another sentence.

Answer (score -3):

I think you are using firefox version below 23.0 my suggestion is to
first upgrade and then proceed

## First Uninstall and reinstall Firefox using Ubuntu software center.

## New version of Firefox is available in Ubuntu software center

## Reboot the system

your firefox will be upgraded to 23.0 version