# Does mixed content detection in browsers apply to data passed via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox

I'm struggling with support of our clients after Firefox update that disabled mixed content by default on the pages.

I'm all for security and stuff, but can someone explain to me how what I'm doing is insecure and is there any way for me to handle it but call every client and explain to them how to disable mixed content via about:config in firefox?

So the setup is like this: I have a webpage that communicate with proprietary devices with embedded http server that runs inside local network (so I can't query the devices from the server side, only from client side), while the pages are served via internet and https.

Now when I request the data from the device via javascript (jQuery $.ajax) I'm getting blocked in recent firefox versions with mixed content exception.
I cannot use http for the main page with javascript as it will be insecure for our clients and I can't change the devices that talk only in plain http, but I have to have my page that is delivered via https to read data from those devices via http.

So the question is, why would it be insecure if the only thing that I'm reading is basically a text that will never be executed. Firefox allows images to load via http, so why not plain text?
Anyone have any idea if it is possible to do this kind of request so it'll look like "passive" content or some other trick that will make it work without triggering active content blocking?
Here's how the data is read on the page currently:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: deviceIp,
      dataType: 'text',
      crossDomain: 'true',
      timeout: 2500,
      data: parameterMap,
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          // process data
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          // handle error
      }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by mixed content? Do you mean cross-domain content?

Comment: it's new check that is enabled by default in Firefox that checks if there's http content references in https pages and vice versa (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635840/mixed-content-blocking-behavior-in-firefox?rq=1) It's not related to cross-domain calls.

Comment: Ok, so what is `deviceIp` defined as? Is your site secure and that URL is insecure?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I need security for my site, so I have to deliver content over https, and I need to get data from device via Ajax, and device only support http protocol. Device IP is a local IP address, but it shouldn't matter really, the problem in question is I'm just retriving plain text status, so I agree that this is mixed content, I just don't get why is it treated as active content (aka javascript that you can sideload and execute)

Comment: Got it. Unfortunately I don't think there is a way around that. But I'm curious to know if anyone has a hacky solution.

Comment: What was your solution?

Comment: My guess about text vs images is that some idiot is bound to eval text. I don't suppose there's any way you can use JSONP + custom filtering to evade the block . . .

Comment: I don't have a good solution... That's why I'm preaching in here :) I have to work with every customer now to explain how to go to about:config and disable mixed active content in firefox or to click on the shield and disable it for current session. That's the only way I can make it work now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `XMLHttpRequest` (and by that `$.ajax`) do count as [active content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent#Passive_content_list).
You cannot know for sure:

- That the `XHR` request itself does not contain sensitive data that would be normally encrypted but can now be read by a man-in-the-middle attacker (MITM) eavesdropping on the unencrypted `XHR`.
- You cannot make sure that the `XHR` response data was not tampered with, as a MITM could have replaced the unencrypted data. This is, as already noted in the comments, in particular bad if you execute bits from the response. But it might be also bad just do display the data or things based on the data, or store and use compromised data in your process/business logic/reports (or whatever you use the data for).

Please note that it is possible that the MITM is within the local user network, not just the "internet".

Instructing users to change their browser preferences should only be a short term solution at most, and is a really invasive, problematic thing to do, as it disables mixed-content blocking for all sites.

If you cannot change the devices themselves to use https, you could code up some kind of "proxy" or "arbiter", e.g a limited https proxy that would run locally on a user machine and that wraps the communication with devices into https, or a Firefox add-on which, being more powerful than a website in what it can do, carries out the requests for your site.
That way your site and users may still fall victim to device impostors and eavesdropping, but that might a risk you and your users can live with, however your users won't need to disable mixed-content blocking for all sites anymore.